# Would a rooting compound or hormone speed-up the rate at which sod roots in or improve the quality fo those roots?

Tags: roots, lawn, rooting-hormone, sod

I know that at the moment the sod it laid it needs to be watered till squishy - this would probably wash away any additive. But over the subsequent days a solution of either commercial or home-made rooting compound could be applied.

Would this improve the speed or quality of root growth and establishment?

Answer (score 1):

How large is your new lawn?  Sod is so very great at rooting, I am sure that rooting hormone WOULD NOT BE COST EFFECTIVE.  Once you've laid your sod, ROLL with a water filled roller to increase soil/root contact.  Water well...squishy...I don't feel is necessary.  Allow to dry slightly to encourage roots to grow deeper.  It should take a week or two to root well enough to start mowing.  If you can grab your sod like hair and there is resistance to being pulled up, you are able to mow.  DO NOT MOW SHORTER THAN 3".  Lots of other lawn how-to's to read on this site!!  I can not stress enough how important it is to leave at least 3" top growth...for lawn seed mixes that work in the Pacific Northwest and similar zones.  These seed mixtures are composed of grasses that genetically have large root systems.  If there is not enough topgrowth to FEED these roots, you'll have stressed grass and weeds can easily compete.  No amount of fertilizer can supplement.  Use an organic lawn fertilizer such as Dr. Earth's Lawn fertilizer.  Use fewer times per year but WOW!!  The difference is spectacular!!  Aerate once per year!!  Water very deeply and ALLOW TO DRY before watering again!! Mow at least once per week...more is great.  Remove debris.  I've never found a decent 'mulching' mower and the 'clean green' is great spread thinly over your beds. Dr. Earth's has bacteria necessary for decomposing lawn debris and all of the lawns I used this on never needed thatching.  Forget about rooting compound. If it worked...I'd have heard about it...I've seen sod root quite well in gravel without any water...ugh.  Not a big deal.